# Ants moving from A to B and back

Tags: mathematics

I am trying quantitative aptitude questions of a qualifying exam and I couldn't solve this question.

> A stream of ants go from point A to point B and return to A along the same path. All the ants move at a constant speed and from any given point 2 ants pass per second one way. It takes 1 minute for an ant to go from A to B. Ho many returning ants will an ant meet in its journey from A to B?
>
> a: 120
> b: 60
> c: 240
> d: 180

I marked A as that ant will meet 120 ants as at a point only 2 ants can pass per second.

But answer is

> C

Comment: Please make the effort to type in the question instead of just posting a picture. This ensures that the question will be found when someone uses the search function. Making the title descriptive is helpful too.

Comment: In the last couple of days you've posted no fewer than seven of these questions. Maybe dial it back a bit?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan and most of them went to NHQ - they must be _that_ good.

Comment: @Andrew Savinykh what does NHQ means?

Comment: @user795826 It's a typo; he meant HNQ, which means "hot network questions". See the sidebar on the right.

Comment: @Joseph Sible - Reinstate Monica Ok!! I got it.

Comment: The other bit of context needed to understsand Andrew's comment is that unfortunately Puzzling questions that get to HNQ are _not_ the best ones. The HNQ algorithm prefers questions with lots of answers, and on Puzzling that's usually a sign either of a question that's too broad and vague, or of a question that for some reason attracts lazy answerers who haven't bothered to read what's already there. IQ-test-type questions often produce both of those effects.

Comment: If someone posts a _really great_ puzzle here and it attracts a _really great_ answer, it might get HNQed, but usually not. (Because the formula has a term in it like "number of answers times question score", and really great puzzles don't usually produce a lot of answers, and to be HNQ-worthy with only one or two answers the question's score needs to be _very_ high.)

Comment: I wish exam questions could sort their options in ascending order. :D

Comment: @Cœur, some exams put the options randomly so as not to create bias. Also, this question about ants going on a stick reminds me of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/maximum-time-for-ants-to-fall-off-stick).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the situation at the moment the ant is about to start moving from A to B.

> The ant will meet all the ants that are already returning from B to A. It will also meet all the ants that are ahead of him and moving to B, because they will all reach B before him and turn around and meet him while he is not yet at B.

To answer the question we therefore have to work out

> the total number of ants that are currently between A and B.

Consider the first ant he meets.

> This ant left A two minutes ago since he went to B and back. Our ant will therefore meet all the ants that left point A in the last two minutes. At 2 ants per second, that is 240 ants.

Comment: This is a more intuitive answer than mine.

Comment: I think this expressly means that what what we understand by meeting. If you think that Newton means Bing between point ine and point b then pause the answer would be 240 but effect means passing by then the answer should actually 120.

Comment: @Pandey_Ji I don't understand what you mean. There are 240 ants that he meets going the other way. Half of them were going in the opposite direction at the start. The other half were going at the same speed and in the same direction as him at the start, but turn around and meet him during that minute.

Comment: The one point is that this assumes that our ant is somewhere in the middle of the stream, starting after at least a minute has passed. For example, if he is first, he will not pass any on his way from A to B.

Comment: @Damila I almost posted a nearly identical comment on the OP right now lol - also, your answer was more intuitive, for me personally at least. So thanks for posting.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis. My apologies. I actually thought about putting that as comment. But, later on read your answer once again and I deleted the comment. But it appears that it was posted twice and also with various typos. I just realised that enter button of my phone is posting the comment, rather than entering a new line.

Comment: But, tell me, would you be confused if 239, would have been an option as well? Because, for 240, we are counting the first ant which our ant has crossed entering while entering the line A, and hence it may not be counted as for moving from A to B.

Comment: @Pandey_Ji I agree. The first ant it meets after leaving A will itself have left A just *under* 2 minutes ago. The returning ant that left A exactly 2 minutes ago will be also be at A at the start. A good argument could certainly be made that 239 is a better answer. If ants not only turned around at B but also at A, then you would have 240 ants in total, and our ant would meet the 239 other ants exactly once on his trip from A to B.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is

> $C$

The reason is

> Our ant's **relative velocity** to the returning ants is **4 ants per second**

The explanation:

> -If our ant was not moving, then 2 ant-lengths per second would pass him, and 120 ants per minute would pass him.
>  -But our ant is moving from A to B at a velocity of 2 ant-lengths per second.
>  -Returning ants are moving from B to A at a velocity of 2 ant-lengths per second.
>  -Therefore, our ant is moving relative to the returning ants at **4 ant-lengths per second** (2+2).
>  -60 seconds per minute * 4 ant-lengths per second = 240 ant-lengths per minute.

Answer (score 4):

While the reasoning below has [already been given](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99295/44845), here is a more visual example.

> 120 Ants would be correct if the other line of ants was **stationary**.  Because the ants in the other line are *also* moving, they pass each other on the half-tick as well as the full-tick (each "tick" here being half a second, as 2 ants pass each point in a second)
>
>  This has the effect of doubling the number of ants encountered.
>
>  [image: A Red ant moves up, while Green, Blue and Yellow ants move down]

Comment: That looks like ants from SimAnt

Answer (score 3):

Stating the question in another way: pick any point between A and B and you will see two ants pass that point each second in each direction. It doesn't say two ants per second pass each other. I think that's where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: Yes you are right!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking this as it is a constant stream of ants and we're looking at an ant starting while the stream has been going on for at least 2 minutes.

> If two ants pass any point each second, then there must be *120* ants on the path from B to A heading towards A.
>  If we divide the path into 60 segments since it takes 60 seconds to get from A to B,
>  each segment will have two ants in it.  In once second they will pass the point
>  dividing segments and move to the next segment.

But also

> Since it is a constant stream of ants, there will be more coming while our ant makes
>  his journey.  How many?  The same number that reach point B and start back towards
>  A while our ant is making his journey from A to B.  That's the ants that are on the path from A to B when our ant starts, 2 per second over 60
>  seconds, or another *120*.

Therefore

> There are 120 ants in motion from B to A and another 120 in motion from A to B that
>  will turn around at B and meet us on their return journey, so the answer is
>  **240 ants**.

Comment: What do you mean on the field?  I would take it to be the ants going from $A$ to $B$ plus the ants going from $B$ to $A$ at any instant.  In that case there are $240$ at any point in time.  Our ant meets the $240$ who started before him.  The $241st$ was off the field before our ant started,  The $240th$ leaves just as our ant arrives.

Comment: I meant on the return path